# DNSCache загружает процессор и блокирует интернет

Tags: windows-10

**OS**: Windows 10 LTSC 1809 (сборка 17763.1339)

Сразу после загрузки Windows минут 10-15 процесс **dnscache** загружает CPU на ~50%, при этом не открываются сайты в браузере, не работают приложения, требующие доступа в интернет (Google Drive, Discord, лаунчеры онлайн-игр и т.д.). Через 10-15 минут этот процесс успокаивается и всё начинает работать как положено. Но если внести какие-то изменения в файл HOSTS, то всё начинается заново - опять 10-15 минут тормозов и неработающие браузер/приложения.

При этом команда

```
ping 8.8.8.8
```

работает нормально, даже пока dnscache делает свое черное дело.

Сам файл HOSTS у меня крупный (использую HOSTS отсюда: https://github.com/StevenBlack/hosts), но в Linux этот же самый файл не вызывает никаких проблем, да и на старой винде тоже проблем с ним не было.

К роутеру у меня подключено 2 ПК (проводом) и 2 телефона (по Wi-Fi), при этом такая проблема наблюдается только на одном компе и только в Windows 10 (на нем еще стоит Ubuntu, в ней такой проблемы нету). На остальных устройствах все в порядке, никаких тормозов при загрузке и интернет сразу доступен во всех приложениях.

Началось все это почти сразу после установки системы, точно сказать не могу, либо вообще сразу же, либо на 2й-3й день. Переустанавливать систему не хочется, может быть есть какой-то способ решения этой проблемы? (только обязательно с сохранением функционирования файла HOSTS, без него не вариант, не хочется терпеть тонны рекламы и трекинга во всяких встроенных недобраузерах в играх или оверлее Steam; *собственно, сама эта винда у меня стоит только для игр, которые совсем не совместимы с Линуксом*).

Comment: Забыл добавить - перед публикацией вопроса проверял ПК свежескачанным антивирусом AVZ, ни одной проблемы не обнаружено.

Comment: Отключи службу dnscache и посмотри чо выйдет. https://translated.turbopages.org/proxy_u/en-ru.ru.d363ee06-638e0898-9ce9d44b-74722d776562/https/social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/a04284f9-cf27-4f37-82fe-31255f70625f/how-to-disable-windows-10-dns-cache-services

Comment: Попробовал отключить службу, вроде бы помогло. Винда после загрузки не тормозила, интернет сразу был доступен в браузере. Проверю потом еще пару раз/перезагрузок для надежности. Файл HOSTS вроде бы работает, по крайней мере `ping doubleclick.net` стучался на 127.0.0.1
Спасибо за подсказку, сам я видел подобное решение в поиске гугла, но побоялся, что HOSTS перестанет обрабатываться при отключенной службе :)

Comment: напишу тогда ответом, пусть плюсы в карму идут))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно отключить службу dnscache. Служба занимается созданием кэша dns записей.На пользовательских машинах Для пользовательских машин это не критично. Будет делать немного больше запросов на dns сервер провайдера.
Подробно как отключить написано тут. [Как отключить dnscache](https://translated.turbopages.org/proxy_u/en-ru.ru.d363ee06-638e0898-9ce9d44b-74722d776562/https/social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/a04284f9-cf27-4f37-82fe-31255f70625f/how-to-disable-windows-10-dns-cache-services)